# run animation for buttons one after an other

Tags: android, animation

I use animation to display my buttons, i have 9 buttons so i used duration for display, but it is run animation for all buttons at same time and just with diffrent duration, of course it is correct, but i want to run animation for button1 first and when it is done, do it again for button2 and when it is done too, do it for next buttons....
I mean run same animation with same speed for different buttons one after another,not same time. now my apk is this:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9Q0pN8FVwEORGRQVE1kQmtvS28/view?usp=sharing

it must be like this:

http://up.vbiran.ir/uploads/4517142605716735676_animationn.gif

my full code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public MediaPlayer player;
    public MediaPlayer playerp;

    private final ButtonSupport[] buttonSupports = new ButtonSupport[]{
            new ButtonSupport(R.id.Button06, 1000l, YourClassActivity.class),
            new ButtonSupport(R.id.Button03, 2000l,YourClassActivity2.class),
            new ButtonSupport(R.id.button1, 3000l,YourClassActivity3.class),
            new ButtonSupport(R.id.Button08, 5000l,YourClassActivity4.class),
            new ButtonSupport(R.id.Button04, 6000l,YourClassActivity5.class),
            new ButtonSupport(R.id.Button01, 7000l,YourClassActivity6.class),
            new ButtonSupport(R.id.Button07, 9000l,YourClassActivity7.class),
            new ButtonSupport(R.id.Button05, 10000l,YourClassActivity8.class),
            new ButtonSupport(R.id.Button02, 11000l,YourClassActivity9.class),
    };

    private static class ButtonSupport{
        final int buttonId;
        final long duration;
        final Class<? extends Activity> clazz;

        ButtonSupport(int buttonId, long duration, Class<? extends Activity> clazz) {
            this.buttonId = buttonId;
            this.duration = duration;
            this.clazz = clazz;
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        for (ButtonSupport buttonSupport : buttonSupports) {
            animButton(buttonSupport);
        }

    }

    private void animButton(final ButtonSupport buttonSupport) {
        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(buttonSupport.buttonId);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startButtonAnimation(v, buttonSupport.clazz);
            }
        });
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.push_right_in);
        anim.setDuration(buttonSupport.duration);
        button.startAnimation(anim);
    }

    public void startButtonAnimation(View btn, final Class<? extends  Activity> clazz) {
        Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.shake);
        btn.setAnimation(shake);
        btn.startAnimation(shake);

        shake.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                player = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.music);
                player.setLooping(true); // Set looping
                player.setVolume(1,1);
                player.start();

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                player.stop();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), clazz));
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation, R.anim.animation2);
                playerp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.musicp);
                playerp.setLooping(false); // Set looping
                playerp.setVolume(1,1);
                playerp.start();


            }

        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

animation xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%p" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="1000"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="1000" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest change to make it work looks like this:

```
int ANIM_OFFSET=100;

....

for (int i=0;i<buttonSupports.length;i++) {
    ButtonSupport buttonSupport =buttonSupports[i];
    animButton(buttonSupport,i);
}

....

anim.setStartOffset(i*ANIM_OFFSET);
```

Comment: That's one solution i prefer to do. Another solution, you can use `AnimationSet` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html